# Another word for 'mutual trust' but not 'reciprocal confidence'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there another word for 'mutual trust' but not the phrase 'reciprocal confidence' ?

Example sentence:
It is the **WORD HERE** between Mrs Doe and organisation XYZ that enables to gain deeper and more profound insights into these phenomena.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't like 'mutual trust' and 'reciprocal confidence?'. It could help get an idea of what you're looking for. You could just use 'trust' since you mention it is between the 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Rapport (noun)

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rapport)

> *Meaning*: **A close and harmonious relationship in which the people or groups concerned understand each other's feelings or ideas and communicate well.**
>
> > *Usage*: "Dermot and Bridie quickly established a **rapport** with the people of the town and hinterland."
> >
> > *Usage*: "**Rapport** is really about reducing the differences between you and your client, and building your similarities."

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rapport)

> *Meaning*: **a friendly, harmonious relationship; especially : a relationship characterized by agreement, mutual understanding, or empathy that makes communication possible or easy**
>
> > *Usage*: "Slick subordinates who establish a **rapport** with investors may start acting like your equals."

Your sentence:

> "It is the **rapport** between Mrs Doe and organisation XYZ that enables to gain deeper and more profound insights into these phenomena."

Comment: Smashing - thank you - answer accepted and upvoted!